# PHP MySQL Query group by items

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm getting this JSON result from mySQL with the following php query:

```
/* grab the posts from the db */
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ko_timetable";
 $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

 /* create one master array of the records */
 $posts = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {

while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    } 
}
```

**JSON Result**:

```
post =         {
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "Intro/General";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
ID = 19;
"ORDER_BY" = 5;
TIME = "1:00pm - 2:30pm";
};
}
{
post =         {
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "General/Intermediate/Advanced";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai Spar - Competitive";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
ID = 27;
"ORDER_BY" = 5;
TIME = "6:00pm - 9:00pm";
};
},
{
post =         {
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "Fighters/Advanced/Intermediate";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Fighters Training";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Monday;
ID = 1;
"ORDER_BY" = 1;
TIME = "9:30am - 11:00pm";
};
```

But how can I change this query to get this result group by "DAY_OF_WEEK".  See example below, thanks for your help:

```
{
Sunday =         {
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "Intro/General";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
ID = 19;
"ORDER_BY" = 5;
TIME = "1:00pm - 2:30pm";
};
{
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "General/Intermediate/Advanced";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai Spar - Competitive";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
ID = 27;
"ORDER_BY" = 5;
TIME = "6:00pm - 9:00pm";
};
},
{
Monday =         {
"CLASS_LEVEL" = "Fighters/Advanced/Intermediate";
"CLASS_TYPE" = "Fighters Training";
"DAY_OF_WEEK" = Monday;
ID = 1;
"ORDER_BY" = 1;
TIME = "9:30am - 11:00pm";
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Also, whatever this is, it's not JSON.

Comment: @Truth, the question is **How can I change this query to get this result group by "DAY_OF_WEEK"?**...

Comment: @HernandoZ: This is not JSON response. Please show us the genuine JSON output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DAY_OF_WEEK as array index like this,

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $posts[$posts["DAY_OF_WEEK"]] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
```

But remember that in the example you have shown the indexes of array are names of the days then the result of previous Sunday will be replaced with this weeks Sunday and so on so forth.
You could also use a count variable to avoid replacing of keys with duplicate names, like this.

```
$count = 1;
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $posts[$posts["DAY_OF_WEEK"].$count] = array('post'=>$post);
      $count++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , is perfect , how can I tag "DAY_OF_WEEK" so it shows DAY = Monday ({ post = ..... Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example how you want Json to be displayed because I am not getting your point.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $posts[ $post['DAY_OF_WEEK'] ] = $post;
}
```

Comment: That would overwrite duplicate DAY_OF_WEEK array keys. For example, if it adds $post to $posts['sunday'] and then tries to add a different post which also uses sunday, the first one is over-written. Instead try: `$posts[$post['DAY_OF_WEEK']][] = $post;`

Comment: @acido69 Cillosis is right , cillosis is you summit your answer i'll accepted , thanks